# IF NOT EXISTS within a RETURN QUERY statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, set-returning-functions

I have a PostgreSQL function which takes in a list of strings, matches such strings within a `Word` table and returns them accordingly. `Word` is a table consisting of a string `word` as a primary ID and attributed features to that string.

This is the working version of the function.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION equals_words(words Text[]) RETURNS SETOF "Word" AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  w Text;
BEGIN
  FOREACH w IN ARRAY $1
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "Word" WHERE word = w
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE STRICT;
```

I would like the the statement within the loop to check whether the query returned nothing, and if so, call another function `longest_prefix(w TEXT)` which attempts to match `w` with its longest prefix. This is what I have so far.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION equals_words(words Text[]) RETURNS SETOF "Word" AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  w Text;
BEGIN
  FOREACH w IN ARRAY $1
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY 
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "Word" WHERE word = w)
        BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM longest_prefix(w); 
        END
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE STRICT;
```

This does not work, giving me the below error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 8:   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "Word" WHERE word = w)
```

I suspect NOT EXISTS can not be used within a RETURN QUERY statement but I am not too sure. Can someone suggest an alternative if so?

Comment: There is no need to iterate over the array to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE and `UNION ALL` to put this all in one query:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM "Word" w
      WHERE w.word = w
     )
SELECT cte.*
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM longest_prefix(w)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte);
```

Answer (score 0):

`IF` statements aren't allowed in SQL. But you can of course execute different queries in different branches using `IF` in PL/pgSQL.

```
...
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM "Word" WHERE word = w) THEN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM longest_prefix(w);
ELSE
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "Word" WHERE word = w;
END IF;
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the cases where an exact match can be found, would this execute `SELECT * FROM "Word" WHERE word = w` twice?

Comment: @drew181: Hmm, I don't know how good optimization works for PL/pgSQL, if there's any (which might well not be the case). But since the subquery for `EXISTS` doesn't need to and won't fetch all of the result, one row is enough to know, I don't think there's too much of an overhead here either way.